# Save extra data while User Registration

Tags: laravel, user-registration, laravel-breeze

I am using [Breeze](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/starter-kits)  template.I am working with **User Registration**. My **store()** user function is like below

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|confirmed|min:8',
        ]);

        Auth::login($user = User::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
        ]));

        event(new Registered($user));

        return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
    }
```

I would like to save more data (like user Date of Birth) as **User details**  in another table while Registering User. I would like to maintain one to one relationship with **User** table and **User details** table.

Actually I would like to attache something with this **event(new Registered($user));**. So that I can save data to another Table along with registration. How can I do that ?

Where can I get the code of this **new Registered($user)** ?

Answer (score 0):

create a new instance

and save all other fields with `id` to another table

```
$model2 new model2();

$model->col = $request->1;
$model->fk= $user->id;
$model->save();
```

Comment: Thanks @Chaudhry Asif. Actually I would like to attache something with this event(new Registered($user));. So that I can save data to another Table along with registration. How can I do that ?